# {reloadOnSearch: false} controller does not reload when history back

Tags: angularjs

I have a controller at /page with {reloadOnSearch: false}. When it is initiated, it does this to change url:

```
var query = $location.search();
if (!query.tab) {
    $location.search('tab', 'tab1');
}
```

Then I have a problem. Let's say a user enters this controller from another controller at /another_page. Back button doesn't work because it only goes back to /page and does nothing. The expected behavior should be going back to /another_page. What's the right way to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Use $location.replace() method this will replace window history